# Existence of entire function such that $f(n)=n^2i$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Consider existence of an entire function such that $f(n)=in^2$ and $f(i)=i$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I can't use identity principle in this problem because $\mathbb{N}$ has no limit point. Who can help me to solve this problem?

Comment: You could write one down...

Comment: If $f(n)=n^2i$, what would be a good idea for $f(z)$?

Comment: $g(z) = z^2 i$ almost works, except that $g(i) = -i$.  Can you think of a function $h$ to add to $g$, such that $h(n) = 0$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ but $h(i) \ne 0$?

Comment: Thanks! I got it